# How to prove A → (B ∨ C) given A → B

Tags: logic, philosophy, formal-proofs

How to prove A →  (B ∨ C)  given  A  → B

I know this is a valid argument, I'm just terrible at fitch-style proofs and have no idea how to start, let alone finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm just terrible at fitch-style proofs and have no idea how to start, let alone finish.

Use a **conditional proof** to introduce that conditional statement.  Assume $A$ and then use the premise to derive the conclusion of $B\lor C$.   I do believe you can fill in the rest of the details.

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}$ $$\fitch{1.~~A\to B}{\fitch{2.~~A}{3.~~:\\4.~~B\lor C}\\5.~~A\to(B\lor C)\qquad\text{Conditional Introduction (2-4)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use truth table.

```
A B C A->B A->(BVC)
0 0 0  1     1
0 0 1  1     1
0 1 0  1     1
0 1 1  1     1
1 0 0  0     0
1 0 1  0     1
1 1 0  1     1
1 1 1  1     1
```

You can see that when A $\rightarrow$ B is true, A$\: \rightarrow$(B$\: \vee \:$C) is true.

Or A$\: \rightarrow$(B$\: \vee \:$C)=(A$\rightarrow$B)$\: \vee\:$C $\Rightarrow$ A$\rightarrow$B.

Answer (score 1):

This result is known as 'Weakening the Consequent'.

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}$ $$\fitch{1.~~A\to B\qquad \text{Hypotheses}}{\fitch{2.~~A \qquad \text{Introduction/Conditional Proof}}{3.~~B \qquad \text{Modus Ponens 1, 2} \\4.~~B\lor C \qquad \text{Disjunction Introduction 3}}\\5.~~A\to(B\lor C)\qquad\text{Conditional Proof(2-4)}}$$

Comment: You can use the [Natural deduction proof editor and generator](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) or the [LaTeX fitch package](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/fitch/) to typeset natural deduction proofs.

Comment: You cannot use those on this site. @lemontree

Comment: @GrahamKemp I always screenshot the result and insert it as an image, I consider that method simple enough. Besides, I assume Rob might be interested to know how to typeset ND proofs in general, not just for this site. (A previous version of their post said "I am not sure how to format this as fitch diagram in here. If someone knows, feel free to edit this", hence my comment.)

Answer (score 1):

$$A\to B$$

$$\lnot A\lor B$$

$$(\lnot A\lor B)\lor C$$

$$\lnot A\lor(B\lor C)$$

$$A\to(B\lor C)$$

Is this the kind of proof you want?